# How to get certain term in set of sentences using php

Tags: php, arrays, regex

This is regular expression problem. I want to collect date and xxxxxxxx.php in set of sentences.

Here is my txt :

```
09-10-17 05:56:34 ChartConfig.php (25): DEPRECATED (8192) >> message = Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ChartConfig has a deprecated constructor

09-10-17 05:56:34 Point.php (26): DEPRECATED (8192) >> message = Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Point has a deprecated constructor

09-10-17 05:56:34 XYDataSet.php (26): DEPRECATED (8192) >> message = Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; XYDataSet has a deprecated constructor
```

And I am trying to collect the data like:

```
$date = ["09-10-17 05:56:34","09-10-17 05:56:34","09-10-17 05:56:34"]
$file = ["ChartConfig.php","Point.php","XYDataSet.php"]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: have you tried.... reading the error?

Comment: @Isaac The errors are what he's trying to parse - not what he's getting.

Comment: I dont know how to match between certain word and that sentence. Is there any function in php ?

Comment: I put it on tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you get on track:

```
<?php
$lines = file_get_contents("foo.txt");

preg_match_all("/^(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (.+) \(/Um", $lines, $matches);

list(,$times, $filenames) = $matches;

var_dump($times);
var_dump($filenames);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "09-10-17 05:56:34"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "09-10-17 05:56:34"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "09-10-17 05:56:34"
}
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "ChartConfig.php"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Point.php"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "XYDataSet.php"
}
```

Note that you should check the return value of `preg_match_all` (the number of times the pattern matched) before doing any processing... I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.